# How to convert text to numbers with Invantive SQL?

Tags: sql, invantive-sql

I am using the Invantive Query Tool. What is the right way to convert text to numbers?

I get a text field from my database, constructed in a format like `3,4`. When I use a calculation function in my query for example `2 * 3,4` it shows `68`.

What is the right function to get the right data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to do that now with the existing functions, so I would suggest a workaround. First, you convert the text to a format Invantive SQL understands (US English), and then convert that new text to a number.

```
select to_number(replace('3,4', ',', '.'))
```

Comment: to_number is supported by which engine?

Comment: Invantive SQL @AjanBalakumaran